# Production Electron HTTP calls

Tags: node.js, security, axios, electron

When i build Electron app with ReactJS for production, i see it handles frontend on ://file protocol.

If i create an **express** server on http://localhost, and make HTTP requests, Auth, CRUD operations from the Electron app to my HTTPS backend API server,are they are encrypted/secure?

Comment: Please ask your question only once.

Comment: “*secure*” has *a lot* of different meanings. What’s your threat model, and what mitigations do you have in place for your identified risks?

Comment: @esqew an HTTP server in Electron client side that communicates with an HTTPS API, if it's encrypted

Comment: Because i receive Stripe warning on Production Electron that says it's not HTTPS .